# Set field values on lightning:recordEditForm (record create mode)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I am using `lightning:recordEditForm` to display records that may be new or existing. This is working nicely, however I now want to preset one of the fields. The fields are displayed using `lightning:inputField` components.

I understand that this is potentially stretching `lightning:recordEditForm` beyond its intended use, but since I get query & save functions OOTB I would very much like to continue using it.

So is there a way, using a secret facet or even JS to change field values after they are queried by the component? If not what's the next best thing that doesn't involve Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but basically I tried to set the field value after component-init and it worked:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var fieldValue = component.get('v.fieldValue');
    component.find('input_field').set('v.value', fieldValue);
}
```

where *input_field* is the id of the target `lightning:inputField` component:

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Field__c" aura:id="input_field"/>
```

In my scenario I wanted to have this field hidden so I set the style accordingly and the field got populated "in behind the scenes".

Comment: How did you hide the field?

Comment: Did you use `aura:if` or did you add a css class to the component? [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm) is the documentation which makes me ask this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use value attribute.

`<lightning:inputField fieldName="Field__c" value={!v.foo}/>`

Comment: That does not work. If you will try to submit such a `lightning:recordEditForm` it will give you an error due to lacking fields.